# Can I use while(strstr(name[a],sname)!=NULL)

Tags: c, search, strstr

I'm writing a phonebook application and one of the functions is for searching the phonebook by name.

The program should print out the names the same way as the user entered them (later I will include the numbers and other info). The phonebook has 100 contacts.

`sname` is the name that user have entered to search.

`name[a]` is name list. Is there any other code like `strstr`? Like its operating if its found printing them if not then `print("not found any")` something like this:

```
for(a=1; a<101; a++) {
    while(strstr(name[a],sname) != NULL) {
        printf(strstr(name[a], sname));
    }
}
```

Comment: Indexes, in C, should start at 0 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that: it is an infinite loop.

```
    while(strstr(name[a],sname)!=NULL){
        printf("%s\n",strstr(name[a],sname));
        }
```

None of `a`, `name[a]`, `sname` change in the conditions or body of the `while`

Comment: should i change the place of FOR loop with that While loop ?

Comment: I think you want to replace the `while` with an `if`. The `for` loop appears to be at the correct place in the code structure (but it probably should start at `0`)